# I asked a question about Drupal programming, but it was closed as off-topic. Why?

Tags: support, faq, questions

I have asked a question about an issue I had while developing code for a Drupal module, but the question was closed as off-topic. Still, questions about programming are allowed.

Why was my question closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming questions are allowed, as long as are about Drupal and require specific Drupal knowledge to answer them. This means that a programming question is off-topic, even if it is about Drupal code, if:

- The question is about code that is passing the wrong parameter to a PHP function not implemented by Drupal core or any third-party module
- The question is about code that is making wrong assumptions about the value returned from a PHP function not implemented by Drupal core or any third-party module
- The question is about code that contains a syntax error
- The question is not about a Drush script
- The question is not about a library expressly written for Drupal and used only for Drupal developing

*Questions about Drupal* doesn't mean *all the questions I have about problems I have while developing for, or using, Drupal*; it means *questions that require a specific Drupal knowledge to give the correct answer*. This is also valid for programming questions.